# Testing undesired multiselection using Robotium

Tags: android, eclipse, testing, robotium, android-testing

I want to test an undesired user action using Robotium. Is it possible to test clicking on two different buttons at the same time? If so, can you explain how?

Thank you.

Comment: could you add your code and link to screenshot of your app. It would be easier to explain an example

Comment: i think that it's good question to add it as issue here: https://github.com/robotiumtech/robotium